# Avoid macro running in another Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, private-methods

This code is associated with a .xlsm file, lets say, `X`. When I open `X` file and then open a second file `Y`, the macro from `X` runs into `Y` as well when "delete" or "backspace" is pressed in `Y`. Moreover, if I open `X` and `Y` and then close `X`, but `Y` is still opened - if I press "delete" or "backspace" in `Y`, `X` file will be automatically opened. So, I want to avoid that, I want that the code in `X` just run inside `X`. Hope it isn't too confused!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim TestCell
Dim RE As Object
Dim REMatches As Object
Dim Cell1_1 As String
Dim Today As String
Dim Cell As String

ThisRow = Target.Row

With Worksheets("Input")
Application.OnKey "{DELETE}", "CleanCell1_1"

Application.OnKey "{BACKSPACE}", "CleanCell1_1"
End With

If Target.Column = 9 Then

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Columns("I:I").Columns.AutoFit
Sheets("Input").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFormattingCells:=True
    Sheets("Input").EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

Sheets("Chart").Unprotect
Sheets("Chart").Columns("B:B").Columns.AutoFit
Sheets("Chart").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
Sheets("Chart").EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End If

If Target.Column = 10 Then

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

With RE
    .MultiLine = False
    .Global = False
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "[G,g,Y,y,R,r]"
End With

For Each TestCell In Target.Cells

Set REMatches = RE.Execute(TestCell.Value)

If REMatches.Count > 0 And Len(Target.Value) = 1 Then
    If Len(Cells(1, 1).Value) = 1 Then
        Today = Now()
        Cell1_1 = Sheets("Input").Cells(1, 1).Value
        Range("K" & ThisRow) = Cell1_1 + ": " + Format(Today, "ddmmmyy")
    End If

ElseIf Target.Value <> vbNullString Then
     Row = Target.Row
     Cells(Row, 10).Value = vbNullString
     MsgBox "Please, type only:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "G for Green" & vbNewLine & "Y for Yellow" & vbNewLine & "R for Red"

End If

Next

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is book `Y` being opened via VBA?  Or are you opening the book manually?

Comment: Manually. Normal double click!

Comment: I like Siphor's answer, seems to fit.  The only other suggestion I would add is to open book `Y` in a new instance of Excel.  So go to Start --> Programs --> Excel to open up a separate instance and drag and drop the file on to that instance.  It's a bit cumbersome but it keeps things separate for me.

Comment: The problem is that several people open that file. So I cannot tell everyone to do it. I just want to make a way that x workbook macro just run within itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would activate/deactivate the Application.OnKey when the X workbook is active/not active
Like this:
In ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate() 
    Application.OnKey "{DELETE}", "CleanCell1_1"
    Application.OnKey "{BACKSPACE}", "CleanCell1_1"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate() 
    Application.OnKey "{DELETE}", ""
    Application.OnKey "{BACKSPACE}", ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Siphor. Thx! But, it hasn't really worked out. Shall I paste it into workbook "X"?

Comment: Hi Siphor. I've used your tip together with another trick. I have used a kind of shortcut together with that. I've used a module as well:

If ActiveWorkbook.Name = "NAME.xlsm" Then Call CleanCell1_1