# How to stop a macro in one workbook from calling another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro I created in one workbook (workbook A). It works and runs fine.

I need to use another workbook (workbook B) created by someone else that also has macros in it. When they are both open at the same time, and I run Workbook A, it calls a public function in workbook B on every loop iteration unwantedly.

It should not call anything from Workbook B, there are no names the same nor any calls or programed interaction between the two workbooks.  The answer is unaltered but the processing time is increased drastically.

I cannot share code details but am looking for a way to block this interaction.

Can I make a spreadsheet only be able to get data from itself without making that the case for all my spreadsheets?  Any ideas on a fix are appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing your code, if you have any code that has activecell or activesheet and your other workbook is the active one, your code will run on that workbook. View [this link it might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520051/avoid-macro-running-in-another-excel-file)

Comment: You could disable the public function in Workbook B that is being activated. The function may be firing when a specific change in the activesheet happens. You need to look at the public function and try fix the code.

Comment: The workbook B function is being called by a calculation cycle. Suspend calculation with application.calculation = xlcalculationmanual during sub procedure processing and reassert it with application.calculation = xlcalculationautomatic before exiting the sub.